# Writing Neo4J Cypher query in C#

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have an MVC Asp.Net application that is connected to a Neo4j database. In my database there is a relationship `(m:Movie)<-[r:HAS_WATCHED_MOVIE]-(u:User)` between `movie` and `user` entities.

What I want to do is return a `IEnumerable<Movie>` that contains top 3 movies (top movies are the movies with most `HAS_WATCHED_MOVIE` relationsips) in descending order.

I have already figured out a Cypher query to do this, and it goes like this:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)<-[r:HAS_WATCHED_MOVIE]-(b) 
RETURN m, COUNT(r) 
ORDER BY COUNT(r) DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Since I'm new with Neo4j C# client, I'm not sure how to go about writing this query in c#?

Comment: Which .NET client are you using? `Neo4j-Driver` or `Neo4jClient`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Using [Neo4jClient](https://github.com/readify/neo4jclient)

```
var client = new BoltGraphClient("bolt://localhost:7687", "neo4j", "neo");
client.Connect();

var query = client.Cypher
                  .Match("(m:Movie)<-[r:HAS_WATCHED_MOVIE]-(b)")
                  .Return((m,r) => new { 
                      Movie = m.As<Movie>(), 
                      Count = r.Count()
                   })
                  .OrderByDescending("Count")
                  .Limit(3);;

foreach(var result in query.Results)
   Console.WriteLine($"'{result.Movie.Title}' had {result.Count} watchers");
```

For this one, I have my `Movie` class defined as:

```
public class Movie{
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

## Using [Neo4j-Driver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-dotnet-driver)

```
using (var driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "neo")))
{
    using (var session = driver.Session())
    {
        using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            IStatementResult results = tx.Run(
            @"MATCH (m:Movie)<-[r:HAS_WATCHED_MOVIE]-(b) 
              RETURN m, COUNT(r)
              ORDER BY COUNT(r) DESC
              LIMIT 3");
            foreach (IRecord result in results)
            {
                var node = result["m"].As<INode>();
                var title = node.Properties["title"]?.As<string>();
                var count = result["COUNT(r)"].As<long>();

                var movie = new Movie {
                      Title = title,
                };

                Console.WriteLine($"'{movie.Title}' had {count} watchers");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NB.** I've only done the `new Movie` bit in this one, as you say you wanted an `IEnumerable<Movie>` response.

## Thoughts

The `Neo4jClient` one doesn't return an `IEnumerable<Movie>` as you're using the `COUNT` call in the `RETURN` you'd need to do something like:

```
var query = gc.Cypher
        .Match("(m:Movie)<-[r:HAS_WATCHED_MOVIE]-(b)")
        .With("m, COUNT(r) AS count")
        .Return((m, r) => m.As<Movie>())
        .OrderByDescending("count")
        .Limit(3);
```

Where you use a `WITH` to do the `COUNT` before returning. You don't *have* to do this with the `Neo4j-Driver` version as you can fake it after the fact, but I would still change the query if all you want is the `Movie` to:

```
IStatementResult results = tx.Run(
            @"MATCH (m:Movie)<-[r:HAS_WATCHED_MOVIE]-(b) 
              WITH m, COUNT(r) AS count
              RETURN m
              ORDER BY count DESC
              LIMIT 3");
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved it using your query for Neo4j Client.